# Problem with residues in Complex Analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

While dealing with residues in Complex Analysis, many books don't care to define the function on singular points. I think it is not rigorous enough. Without defining the function on a point, it is unfair to do integration. In many cases, emphasis on why the point is a singularity gets lost. For example

Complex Variables and Applications by Brown & Churchill 8e Section 69 Example 1 finds

$$\int_C z^2\sin{\left(\frac1z\right)}dz$$.

It directly says $z=0$ is singular point.

If I define $f(0)=z_0\neq0$, then $z=0$ is a singularity because $f$ is not continuous at $z=0$. But if I define $f(0)=0$, then $f$ is continuous but $f^\prime$ is not.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: You seem to think that $\sin (\frac 1 z)$ is bounded. It is not.

Comment: But $\lim_{z\to0}z^2\sin{\frac1z}=0$

Comment: Your statement is only true if you take the limit over real $z$. Don't forget you're working with functions of complex variables.

Comment: @RameshwarSao If we have a removable singularity then it is always assumed that we define $f$ on this point to be the limit at the point, which makes $f$ a holomorphic function. But in your example, the point $z=0$ is an essential singularity, the worst possible case. There is no way to define $f(0)$ in this case to make it continuous. As mentioned above, $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} z^2\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ is not $0$. Take for example the sequence $z_n=\frac{1}{in}$ and check.

Comment: Thanks everyone

Comment: What is $C$? An integral like this is best evaluated by taking $w=1/z$. If for example $C$ is $|z|=r$ anticlockwise for some $r>0$, the new contour would be $|z|=1/r$ clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of the value you define at the singularity has no effect on the integral.  The integral is completely  determined by the boundary you integrating on.  It is the magic of holomorphic functions that this boundary contains information about the singularity.